# Best Way For Copying Filtered List In Excel From One Session To Another?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a huge excel file - I want to copy a subset of rows from one file to another

If I filter data I can copy those filtered rows but I cannot find a way of pasting just those filtered rows into another workbook which is also filtered

Does anyone know an easy way to do that?

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? The behaviour changed between 2003 and 2007 I think.

Answer (score 0):

The "raw" solution is:

> 1. Reading source worksheet used range in Variant Array (VarArrIn)
> 2. Creating an empty copy of the Input Array (VarArrOut)
> 3. Iteration over the rows in (VarArrIn) writen all rows fullfilling
>      the filter condition to (VarArrOut)
> 4. Writing VarArrOut to the target worksheet